# Create a new column in a dataframe by comparing if the same rows appear in different groups in a dataframe and assign relative values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame that looks like this (but 149110 rows instead):

```
df = {'group':['a','a','a','a',
                 'b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b',
                 'c','c','c','c','c',
                 'd','d','d','d','d','d','d',
                'e','e','e','e',],
        'date':[np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),
                np.datetime64('2019-03-12'),np.datetime64('2019-03-12'),np.datetime64('2019-03-12'),np.datetime64('2019-03-12'),
                np.datetime64('2019-03-12'),np.datetime64('2019-03-12'),np.datetime64('2019-03-12'),np.datetime64('2019-03-12'),
                np.datetime64('2019-03-12'),
                np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),
                np.datetime64('2020-01-01'),
                np.datetime64('2019-01-17'),np.datetime64('2019-01-17'),np.datetime64('2019-01-17'),np.datetime64('2019-01-17'),
                np.datetime64('2019-01-17'),np.datetime64('2019-01-17'),np.datetime64('2019-01-17'),
                np.datetime64('2018-12-03'),np.datetime64('2018-12-03'),np.datetime64('2018-12-03'),np.datetime64('2018-12-03')],
        'id':['tom','taliha','alyssa','randyl',
              'tom','taliha','edward','aaron','daniel','jean','sigmund','albus','riddle',
              'fellicia','ron','fred','george','alex',
              'taliha','alyssa','locke','jon','jamie','sam','sydney',
              'jon','jamie','sam','arya'],
        'value':[1,2,3,4,
                7,6,4,8,2,3,5,9,1,
                1,2,3,4,5,
                5,7,6,3,4,1,2,
                3,2,1,4]}
df= pd.DataFrame(df)
df

    group   date    id  value
0   a   2020-01-01  tom     1
1   a   2020-01-01  taliha  2
2   a   2020-01-01  alyssa  3
3   a   2020-01-01  randyl  4
4   b   2019-03-12  tom     7
5   b   2019-03-12  taliha  6
6   b   2019-03-12  edward  4
7   b   2019-03-12  aaron   8
8   b   2019-03-12  daniel  2
9   b   2019-03-12  jean    3
10  b   2019-03-12  sigmund 5
11  b   2019-03-12  albus   9
12  b   2019-03-12  riddle  1
13  c   2020-01-01  fellicia1
14  c   2020-01-01  ron     2
15  c   2020-01-01  fred    3
16  c   2020-01-01  george  4
17  c   2020-01-01  alex    5
18  d   2019-01-17  taliha  5
19  d   2019-01-17  alyssa  7
20  d   2019-01-17  locke   6
21  d   2019-01-17  jon     3
22  d   2019-01-17  jamie   4
23  d   2019-01-17  sam     1
24  d   2019-01-17  sydney  2
25  e   2018-12-03  jon     3
26  e   2018-12-03  jamie   2
27  e   2018-12-03  sam     1
28  e   2018-12-03  arya    4
```

I need a column: `together` that returns 1 if the person has been with in a group with another person in the current group but in the past year.

For example in group 'a' we have 4 people, but tom and taliha were both in a group together in `np.datetime64('2016-03-12')` i.e. they were both in group 'b' together. We can also see that in group 'c' taliha and alyssa were also together. So I want the corresponding value of `together` for group a to have a 1 next to both tom, taliha and alyssa, but 0 for randyl because he hasn't been in a group with anyone else in the past year.

Then for group 'b' and 'c' because no one has been in a group with anyone else in the past year I want the value of `together` to be 0 for everyone.

For group 'd' within the last year we can see that jon, jamie and sam were in the same group i.e. they were part of group 'e'. So the value of `together` for jon, jamie and sam in group 'd' should be a 1 and the rest of the people a 0.

And as there were no data before group 'e', they should all be assigned 0.

Then I want to create another new column: `rel` based on this depending on the value that the people had in the pervious group. I want `rel` to be equal to 1 if that person in the past group had a value lower than the other person and to be -1 if their value was higher.

For example in group 'a' the value of `rel` for tom should be -1 because he had a higher `value` than taliha in 'b' and because of this the value of `rel` for taliha should be 1, because she had a lower `value` than tom in 'b'. For alyssa I want the value of `rel` to be set to -1 because in group d she has a higher `value` than talhia.

Basically the Idea is that the lower the `value` the better. I am trying to rank people by their past `value`. So for group 'a' I need a system that basically shows that
taliha > tom and taliha > alyssa. But we don't know the relationship between tom and alyssa so I have them as the same value. I also don't know the relationship between randyl and everyone else in the group 'a' so I want the value of `rel` set to 0 for him.
If for example I find the relationship like this: person 1 > person 2 > person 3 and no history for person 4. I want to have `rel` to reflect his relationship. I want the value of `rel` to look a little something like this person 1 = 2, person 2 =  0, person 3 = -2 and person 4 = 0.

So I want the resulting DataFrame to look something like this:

```
    group   date    id  value   together    rel
0   a   2020-01-01  tom     1   1           -1
1   a   2020-01-01  taliha  2   1           1
2   a   2020-01-01  alyssa  3   1           -1
3   a   2020-01-01  randyl  4   0           0
4   b   2019-03-12  tom     7   0           0
5   b   2019-03-12  taliha  6   0           0
6   b   2019-03-12  edward  4   0           0
7   b   2019-03-12  aaron   8   0           0
8   b   2019-03-12  daniel  2   0           0
9   b   2019-03-12  jean    3   0           0
10  b   2019-03-12  sigmund 5   0           0
11  b   2019-03-12  albus   9   0           0
12  b   2019-03-12  riddle  1   0           0
13  c   2020-01-01  fellicia1   0           0
14  c   2020-01-01  ron     2   0           0
15  c   2020-01-01  fred    3   0           0
16  c   2020-01-01  george  4   0           0
17  c   2020-01-01  alex    5   0           0
18  d   2019-01-17  taliha  5   0           0
19  d   2019-01-17  alyssa  7   0           0
20  d   2019-01-17  locke   6   0           0
21  d   2019-01-17  jon     3   1           -2
22  d   2019-01-17  jamie   4   1           0
23  d   2019-01-17  sam     1   1           2
24  d   2019-01-17  sydney  2   0           0
25  e   2018-12-03  jon     3   0           0
26  e   2018-12-03  jamie   2   0           0
27  e   2018-12-03  sam     1   0           0
28  e   2018-12-03  arya    4   0           0
```

Comment: What have you tried to solve the issue and why didn't it work?

Comment: I tried using for loops but that took way too long and I wan't able to get it to work correctly. I have tried groupby() but I wasn't able to get it to work together aswell and I also tried creating separate dataframe but that was way too messy and I also couldn't get it to work. The main thing is I don't know a good way to link to past groups e.g. how to link tom from group a to tom in group b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a try. The first task seems rather easy, the second gave me a headache. And my result for the second part differs slightly from your expectation. Maybe you've made a mistake, but most likely it's due to my misunderstanding.

```
from itertools import combinations

df_grps = df.groupby([df.date.dt.year, 'group']).id.apply(set)
df_vals = df.set_index([df.date.dt.year, 'group', 'id']).value
results = {}
for year in sorted(df.date.dt.year.unique())[1:]:
    groups = {}
    for group in df_grps.loc[year].index:
        ids = df_grps.loc[year, group]
        together = set().union(*(
                       i for i in (ids & h for h in df_grps.loc[year-1]) if len(i) > 1
                   ))
        if not together:
            continue
        together = {i: 0 for i in together}
        for i, j in combinations(together, 2):
            for group_old in df_grps.loc[year-1].index:
                if not {i, j} <= df_grps.at[year-1, group_old]:
                    continue
                i_val = df_vals.at[year-1, group_old, i]
                j_val = df_vals.at[year-1, group_old, j]
                if i_val < j_val:
                    together[i] += 1
                    together[j] -= 1
                elif i_val > j_val:
                    together[i] -= 1
                    together[j] += 1       
        groups[group] = together
    if groups:
        results[year] = groups

df_res = pd.DataFrame(
             [
                 [year, group, i, r]
                 for year, groups in results.items()
                 for group, rel in groups.items()
                 for i, r in rel.items()
             ],
             columns=['date', 'group', 'id', 'rel']
         ).set_index(['date', 'group', 'id'])

df.set_index([df.date.dt.year, 'group', 'id'], inplace=True)
df['together'], df['rel'] = 0, 0
df.loc[df_res.index, 'together'] = 1
df.loc[df_res.index, 'rel'] = df_res.rel
```

Result for your sample frame:

```
                          date  value  together  rel
date group id                                       
2020 a     tom      2020-01-01      1         1   -1
           taliha   2020-01-01      2         1    2
           alyssa   2020-01-01      3         1   -1
           randyl   2020-01-01      4         0    0
2019 b     tom      2019-03-12      7         0    0
           taliha   2019-03-12      6         0    0
           edward   2019-03-12      4         0    0
           aaron    2019-03-12      8         0    0
           daniel   2019-03-12      2         0    0
           jean     2019-03-12      3         0    0
           sigmund  2019-03-12      5         0    0
           albus    2019-03-12      9         0    0
           riddle   2019-03-12      1         0    0
2020 c     fellicia 2020-01-01      1         0    0
           ron      2020-01-01      2         0    0
           fred     2020-01-01      3         0    0
           george   2020-01-01      4         0    0
           alex     2020-01-01      5         0    0
2019 d     taliha   2019-01-17      5         0    0
           alyssa   2019-01-17      7         0    0
           locke    2019-01-17      6         0    0
           jon      2019-01-17      3         1   -2
           jamie    2019-01-17      4         1    0
           sam      2019-01-17      1         1    2
           sydney   2019-01-17      2         0    0
2018 e     jon      2018-12-03      3         0    0
           jamie    2018-12-03      2         0    0
           sam      2018-12-03      1         0    0
           arya     2018-12-03      4         0    0
```

PS: I also have a version that stays a bit more within the Pandas framework, but it's longer. I'll post it if you're interested.